# Instaling docker on CentOS 7.4 - docker_transition_unconfined not defined

Tags: docker, centos7

Installed docker-ce with following instructions.

```
yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
yum install docker-ce
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
```

Since we use selinux in the past we used to do

```
setsebool -P docker_transition_unconfined 1
semanage permissive -a docker_t
```

But on CentOS 7.4 I get errors:

```
# setsebool -P docker_transition_unconfined 1
Boolean docker_transition_unconfined is not defined
# semanage permissive -a docker_t
ValueError: docker_t is not a domain type
```

Previously we used to install docker with docker-io. Is it a result of package changes? Is it no longer required? Am I missing some package?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to disable SELinux

`vim /etc/selinux/config`

`// set SELINUX value: "disabled"
SELINUX=disabled`

and then add docker config at `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

`setsebool -P docker_transition_unconfined 1`

reboot the system

`reboot`

Comment: As I said before, 
`# setsebool -P docker_transition_unconfined 1
Boolean docker_transition_unconfined is not defined`
It seems some package which installs these selinux booleans is not installed now. Either because it changed or is not required now. Need to understand which is the case.

Comment: This answer is not helpful! Problems with SELinux are not solved by disabling SELinux.